# What's the point of using immutable.js on redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutability, immutable.js

I just don't get it what is the advantage of using immutable.js and its method (set, map, etc), since we can set state in redux like this

```
state = {
            ...state,
            width: 'small'
          };
```

Is there any difference from

```
state.set('width', 'small');
```

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Because the first one is mutable.

Comment: On the first one I can just return `{}` or if i feel like it maybe `{width: 'small'}` or maybe for some reason i decide to change the datatype and return `[]` The first example is mutable, you can change it to be anything and can potentially break your application if you type something incorrectly.

Comment: sorry, but i really thought the first one was immutable, because you are passing the whole state. saw 2 or 3 videos teaching to make it this way

Comment: No need to be sorry lol! If you dont know the difference you dont know it and were happy to help :)

Comment: FYI your first example is indeed immutable.  It clones state object, then sets the width property.  Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Brandon its only immutable because of how hes returning it. Its not actually immutable in the sense that something else can be returned instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two advantages to use immutable with redux:

1. Developers make mistakes all the time and it is very easy to accidentally mutate state in your reducer instead of cloning it.  The bug goes "uncaught" for a while and then hits you when you least expect it.  ImmutableJS will give you an error pretty quickly if you mess up.
2. Performance: ImmutableJS takes advantage of the immutable nature of things and is able to use data structures and algorithms that can support collection operations like add/remove/modify with better space & time efficiency than the typical "copy the collection and modify the copy" that we tend to do when we have to write it ourself.

Comment: 3. Convenience: When you have a nested structure that you want to alter a part of: `.setIn([ 'products', 'productX', 'cost' ], 500)` and know that `products` and `productX` will be new objects, but `productY` will not, without having to code that logic manually(which comes back to point 1)